# Why Xcode6.3.2 Compiling swift source files TOO SLOW, When I write down this code

Tags: swift, xcode6, xcode6.3.2

**When I write down these codes snippets:**

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var homeCellArr: [Dictionary <String, String>] = [
        ["name": "eee", "pic": "newsIcon"],
        ["name": "dcd", "pic": "taskIcon"],
        ["name": "ccccc", "pic": "cardIcon"],
        ["name": "bbbb", "pic": "mailIcon"],
        ["name": "aa", "pic": "optionIcon"]
    ]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        ......
```

**I found Building and Indexing became too slow**

And CODE Autocomplete also became slow slow slow IN THIS Swift File

Such as I write **self.** 
I must wait 6s or 7s, before autocomplete show up

How to fix this problem?

---

When I noted these codes

```
 //       var homeCellArr: [Dictionary <String, String>] = [
 //           ["name": "eee", "pic": "newsIcon"],
 //           ["name": "dcd", "pic": "taskIcon"],
 //           ["name": "ccccc", "pic": "cardIcon"],
 //           ["name": "bbbb", "pic": "mailIcon"],
 //           ["name": "aa", "pic": "optionIcon"]
 //       ]
```

The speed of code autocomplete turn normal

Comment: The more Xcode needs to compile the longer it takes. That should only happen the first time compiling after you touched & edited the certain area. It should also not be an issue for your customers as the code is precompiled for the iDevices.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. On my machine, your code compiles instantly and autocompletion from `self.` is instant. The trouble may lie elsewhere. (The first thing I would try is quit Xcode and clean the caches...)